# Comparing small and large samples from the same target population

Tags: correlation, sample-size

Is it valid (reliable etc.) to compare a small sample with a large sample (which is made up of several small samples) when both samples are from the same population?

There are 3 firms. Each firm specialises in the manufacture of a particular product, hence it is classified in that way.

Firm A manufactures common cold medicines, Firm B manufactures arthritis medicines and Firm C manufactures heartburn medicines.

The common element linking the three firms is that they are all medicine manufacturers.

Now, Firm A and C only produce generic medicines and Firm B only produces branded medicines.

I have a sample of 80 workers from each firm and I want to test how satisfied they are in regard to their work-life balance. I am using correlation analysis etc.

I am comparing Firm A with B and C but I also want to compare Firm A and C with B. (Firm A and C are grouped together because they are generic medicine providers).

Is comparing a sample of 80 peoples (Firm B) with a sample of 160 people (Firm A and C) any reason for statistical concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a normal distribution of your outcomes (the work-life balance score?), standard error, confidence intervals and correlation significance levels can change with the size of the sample population (company A, B, C).

For example, if you are using a Pearson correlation to test the relationship between a work-balance score and some other variables, one rule of thumb is that if the correlation coefficients are less than 1.96 / sqrt(popSize) you can not reject the null hypothesis, meaning the correlation coefficients are not significant. There are more accurate techniques to check for [significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) but the short answer is that the size does have an impact on your analysis, especially for the population sizes you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the workers are representative, you could sample (serveral) sets of 80 people from the 160 people and compare each set to the other 80 people.